# How to override the .tittle class and .bar class of ionic.css for IOS?

Tags: android, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to override the .title and .bar class of ionic.css for IOS, I it is working fine for Android and Browser but when i run the project in IOS both classes are not override. You can see it in bellow link for Android and IOS both

IOS
http://s12.postimg.org/hg02wfdu5/IMG_7242.png

Android
http://s24.postimg.org/f1q2ictit/Screenshot_2015_08_22_13_46_19.png

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Add your own css style's  in style.css file, than check it in Ios

Comment: i have added already but it is only working for Android and Browser not for  IOS.

Comment: can you put your code in github or codepen to have a look